# Stack Overflow Jobs needs to be more transparent about if/how it uses account info when applying while logged in

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

So just now, I had to go into Incognito Mode to apply for a position posted on Stack Overflow Jobs because there isn't enough information provided during the process of applying to a posted job via the direct Apply form for me to have a proper understanding of whether the potential employer to whom I'm sending my resume and personal details will be shown my Stack Overflow account or not.

The whole reason I have an anonymous Stack Overflow account is because I have no desire to share my lack of knowledge with the world (and no, the answers I give to help others don't offset the perceived incompetence of asking questions about basic things while learning, especially to a potential hiring manager who's likely to only lightly skim through my activity rather than paying attention to details).

If all being logged in while applying does is allow the user to track/manage applications, and the user's Stack Overflow account name/page isn't shared, then that's fine, but I need to know that up front while trying to apply.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the scenarios:

- If you have a Developer Story and you do not upload a resumé then we send a PDF of your story, a link to the live version & your cover letter.
- If you have a Developer Story and you do upload a resumé then we send the resumé, a link to your story & your cover letter.
- If you do not have a Developer Story (the account you posted as here doesn't) then we just send the uploaded resumé & your cover letter.

Other than that we don't link your application to anything Stack Overflow related.

The first two are pretty obvious when you apply:

[image: Developer Story PDF]

[image: Developer Story Link]